# Site having issues on android

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, jquery

I have http://strutmymutt.com/ for which normal signup and facebook login is not working on Android mobile phones. On the main splash page http://strutmymutt.com/, there is 2 buttons "connect with facebook" and "Use standard signup" but these are working fine everywhere, but not on Android

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine on my 4.2.2 Android phone.  Are you using the emulator?  Do you have facebook installed on the emulator or device and an account that can access it?

Comment: Can you please send me any screen shot

Comment: screen shot of what? It looked on my Android phone exactly how it looked when I browsed to your site on my desktop. Pat yourself on the back